# Getting nested data in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database like in image below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epEaO.png]

I want to make a function `public int getTotalInvites(int userId)` that's return the count of invited users of the user nested

for example: `getTotalInvites(1)` returns 6 because user 1 invite the user 2 (User 2 invite user 5 and 6), 3 and user 4 (User 4 invite user 7), so total is 6.

I want to make the function recursive but Firebase uses callbacks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but doubt if adding more words will help clarify. Can you edit your question to show the code of what you've already tried?

Comment: I don't have a code, i want to make the function but i don't have any idea

Answer (score 0):

Since all data needed for the invite count is stored under a single node, you can do the entire calculation with a single `ValueEventListener`.

Something like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long count = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            count = count + userSnapshot.child("invitedUsers").getChildrenCount();
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

The above code handles a list of users, each of which has an `inviteCount`. If there is somehow a tree of users, you may need to recursively descend the tree with something like a `countUsers(DataSnapshot snapshot)` that you call from within `onDataChange`. But since your JSON is quite flat, there is no need for that here.